# listview hide on orientation change android

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I am using custom list view inside fragment(From Api). on orientation change data is still in array list and also list view get notified but it hides when screen rotates.
here is the code:

```
public class FragNotice extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    ListAdapter listAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    EditText editTextNotice;
    private Button btnSearch;
    private Button btnClear;
    private int incre = 1;
    private boolean boolScroll = true;

    public FragNotice() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(getActivity()));
        setRetainInstance(true);
        search(true);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return init(inflater.inflate(R.layout.notice_activity, container, false));
    }

    private View init(View view) {
        editTextNotice = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextNotice);
        btnSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnClear = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewNotice);
        listView.setOnScrollListener(onScrollListener());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (listAdapter==null) {
            listAdapter=new ListAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<ListRowItem>());
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    AsyncRequest.OnAsyncRequestComplete onAsyncRequestComplete = new AsyncRequest
            .OnAsyncRequestComplete() {


        @Override
        public void asyncResponse(String response, int apiKey) {
                switch (apiKey) {
                    case 1:
                        listView(response);
                        break;
                }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnClear) {
            incre = 1;
            boolScroll = true;
            editTextNotice.setText(null);
            if (listAdapter != null)
                listAdapter.clear();
            search(true);
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSearch) {
            String std = editTextNotice.getText().toString();

            if (std.trim().length() > 1) {
                incre = 1;
                boolScroll = true;
                if (listAdapter != null)
                    listAdapter.clear();
                try {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService
                            (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(new View(getActivity()).getWindowToken(),
                            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                search(false);
            } else
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Please enter atleast two character.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
        }
    }


    class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListRowItem> {
        private final Context context;


        public ListAdapter(Context asyncTask, java.util.List<ListRowItem> items) {
            super(asyncTask, R.layout.notice_listitem, items);
            this.context = asyncTask;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            final ListRowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.notice_listitem, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtSno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSno);
                holder.txtNoticePublishDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id
                        .txtNoticePublishDate);
                holder.btnView = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnView);
                holder.txtNoticeDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id
                        .txtNoticeDescription);
                holder.txtNoticeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNoticeName);


                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.txtSno.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
            holder.txtNoticeDescription.setText(new AppUtility().TitleCase(rowItem.getDescription
                    ()));
            holder.txtNoticeName.setText(new AppUtility().TitleCase(rowItem.getFileTitle()));

            try {
                holder.txtNoticePublishDate.setText(String.valueOf((new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM " +
                        "yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US)).format((new SimpleDateFormat
                        ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US)).parse(rowItem.getUpdateDate()))));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                holder.txtNoticePublishDate.setText(new AppUtility().TitleCase(rowItem
                        .getUpdateDate()));
            }
            holder.btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }

        /*private view holder class*/
        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtSno;
            TextView txtNoticeName;
            TextView txtNoticeDescription;
            TextView txtNoticePublishDate;
            Button btnView;

        }
    }

    class ListRowItem {
        private final String FileTitle;
        private final String Description;
        private final String ContentType;
        private final int DocumentUploadID;
        private final String UpdateDate;

        ListRowItem() {
            this.FileTitle = "";
            this.Description = "";
            this.ContentType = "";
            this.DocumentUploadID = 0;
            this.UpdateDate = "";
        }

        ListRowItem(String fileTitle, String description, String contentType, int
                documentUploadID, String updateDate) {
            this.FileTitle = fileTitle;
            this.Description = description;
            this.ContentType = contentType;
            this.DocumentUploadID = documentUploadID;
            this.UpdateDate = updateDate;
        }

        public String getFileTitle() {
            return FileTitle;
        }

        public int getDocumentUploadID() {

            return DocumentUploadID;
        }

        public String getUpdateDate() {

            return UpdateDate;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return Description;
        }

        public String getContentType() {

            return ContentType;
        }
    }

    private void listView(String response) {
        try {
            ArrayList<ListRowItem> lstItem;
            if(listAdapter==null){
                Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ListRowItem>>() {
                }.getType();
                lstItem = new Gson().fromJson(response, listType);
                listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), lstItem);
            } else {
                Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ListRowItem>>() {
                }.getType();
                lstItem = new Gson().fromJson(response, listType);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    listAdapter.addAll(lstItem);
                } else {
                    for (ListRowItem items : lstItem) {
                        listAdapter.add(items);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (listAdapter != null)
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }


    private AbsListView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener() {
        return new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {


            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                int threshold = 5;
                int count = listView.getCount();

                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count - threshold) {

                        if (boolScroll) {
                            if (editTextNotice.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
                                search(false);
                            else
                                search(true);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                                 int totalItemCount) {
            }
        };
    }

    private void search(boolean bool) {
        String URL;
        if (bool) {
            URL = new SqLite(getActivity()).returnDefaultURI() + "notice/0/" + incre;
            incre = incre + 1;
        } else {
            URL = new SqLite(getActivity()).returnDefaultURI() + "notice/" +
                    editTextNotice.getText().toString().trim() + "/" + incre;
            incre = incre + 1;
        }

        AsyncRequest asyncRequest;
        if (incre > 2)
            asyncRequest = new AsyncRequest(onAsyncRequestComplete, getActivity(), "GET", null,
                    null, 1);
        else
            asyncRequest = new AsyncRequest(onAsyncRequestComplete, getActivity(), "GET", null,
                    "Fetching data", 1);

        asyncRequest.execute(URL);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When orientation changes the activity reloads again.So you have to override onConfigurationChanged method.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

            //Your Code Here
        }
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //Your Code Here
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have put layout also in layout-land folder. and this method isn't calling on orientaion change.
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

            readingAdapter(lstItem);
        }
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            readingAdapter(lstItem);
        }
    }

Comment: help me. i didn't get why is list view hiding . i handled config change and put layout also in layout-land folder

Comment: Set the adapter again when configuration changes...Hope that helps

Comment: yeah... i was just notifying the adapter setting adapter again works and listview scroll posiotion is not lossing. each roation calling onViewCreated so  i am setting adapter from list item here if it is not null. why onConfigchanges is not calling.

Comment: Put this line in your activity tag in menifest: android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" Hope this helps.

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the data into the `ListView` again. You are binding the `ListView` to an adapter, you need to do it in `onConfigurationChanged()` method.

Answer (score 0):

create a directory layout-land in the resources copy the your .xml file there align and set the `Edittext` and Button according to landscape layout .may be it solved your problem if the `listview` doest not get enough space to show in landscape layout

Answer (score 0):

In `onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)` method above you are setting new empty arraylist every time. So the previous items which are loaded are removed from adapter even though it is retained by `setRetainInstance(true)`

So you should have a Field that holds the arraylist and pass that field to adapter

```
private ArrayList<ListRowItem> listItems = new ArrayList<>()

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (listAdapter==null) {
        listAdapter=new ListAdapter(getActivity(), listItems);//pass the Arraylist here
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Then in `private void listView(String response)` method, add items to that listview created above as

```
   listItems = new Gson().fromJson(response, listType);
   listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: thanks i have done the same. just wondering now if i am using Override onConfig method then list view losing its scroll position on rotation. but in case of(as you tell) its is not losing its scroll position. i don't want to save and restore state of scroll position. why it is not working if i use overrided OnConfig method

Comment: ListView handles those state saving things for you, though I am not sure on completely how it is done. But when you use OnConfig method you have to do that if you need to save the scroll state.